# Checking input grammar and deciding a result

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, grammar

Say I have a string "abacabacabadcdcdcd" and I want to apply a simple set of rules:

abaca->a

dcd->d

From left to right s.t. the string ends up being "abad". This output will be used to make a decision. After the rules are applied, if the output string does not match preset strings such as "abad", the original string would be discarded. ex. Every string should distill down to "abad", kick if it doesn't.

I have this hard-coded right now as regex, but there are many instances of these small rule sets. I am looking for something that will take a set of simple rules and compile (or just a function?) into something I can feed the string to and retrieve a result. The rule sets are independent of each other.

The input is tightly controlled, and the rules in use will be simple. Speed is the most important aspect.

I've looked at Bison and ANTLR, but I don't think I need anything nearly that powerful...

What am I looking for?

Edit: Should mention that the strings are made up of a couple letters. Usually 5, i.e. "abcde". There are no spaces, etc. Just letters.

Comment: You're writing a context sensitive grammar, and those are very difficult to reason about. Suppose I add the rule `cabad -> c`. Now which rule should take preference on the example input?

Answer (score 1):

If it is going to go fast, you can start out with a map, that contains your rules as key value pairs of strings. You can then compile this map to a sort of state machine, a tree with char keys, where the associated value is either a replacement string, or another tree.

You then go char by char through your string. Look up the current char in the tree. If you find another tree, look up the next character in that tree, etc. 
At some point, either:

1. the lookup will fail, and then you know that the string you've seen so far is not the prefix of any rule. You can skip the current character and continue with the next.
2. or you get a replacement string. In that case, you can replace the characters between the current char and the last one you looked up inclusive by the replacement string.

The only difficulty is if the replacement can itself be part of a pattern to replace. Example:

```
ab -> e
cd -> b
```

The input:

```
acd -> ab (by rule 2)
ab   -> e (by rule 1) ????
```

Now the question is if you want to reconsider ab to give e?

If this is so, you must start over from the beginning after each replacement. In addition, it will be hard to tell whether the replacement ever ends, except if all the rules you have are such that the right hand side is shorter than the left hand side. For, in that case, a finite string will get reduced in a finite amount of time.

But if we don't need to reconsider, the algorithm above will go straight through the string.